# How to enable push notifications in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to set push notifications for firebase phone authentication. but i could't find push notification [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXlFT.png). What can i do?

Comment: Just type "notification" into the search box.

Comment: i did it. there's no push notification lline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all capabilities are available depending on if you are using a paid Developer Program account, or working with Xcode's free provisioning.

Pertaining to Capabilities/what you can or can't do based on account type - the link is: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/

Answer (score 4):

In **Signing & Capability -> Click on "+Capability"** and type "Push" you will get Push Notification Option. **Now long press on Push Notifications and Drop in your Signing & Capability Window.**

[image]

Comment: i did exactly what u said but there's no push notification line. is it xcode 12

Comment: should i change bundle identifaer?

Comment: Check if you added Push Notification already as It will not come again if its already added. And (no relevant) but restart your Xcode once.

Comment: no i only added background modes. i restarted xcode but it's still no push notification line

Comment: i tryed to open new project and enable push notifications. there's no this option

Answer (score 3):

The reason that the `Push Notifications` is not possible to enable is that you need to have a bundle identifier which has it enabled.

To create a new bundle identifier where push notifications are enabled do the following:

1. Go to the following URL to create a new identifier: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

   - Click on new Identifier (plus symbol, as indicated in the image below)

[image]

2. Select the `App IDs` alternative and press continue.

[image]

3. Select `App` and click continue

[image]

4. Choose a fitting name for your identifier (something like `com.foo.bar`)

   - Here it is required to choose the `explicit` alternative to be able to enable push notifications with your bundle identifier
   - Select the wanted capabilities and you're done with creating a new bundle identifier.

[image]

5. Finally you need to add the new bundle identifier in the Xcode project like shown in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: thank you! Push notification was available after i purchased Developer Program